# "No utilities registered for `I_Display_Type_Controller`" on nextgen gallery ajax call wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, nextgen-gallery

I'm trying to load a nextgen Gallery via ajax, but I getting this error instead

I tried a lot of thing and this is the closer I get

```
function noix_galeria_click() {
  // check nonce
  $nonce = $_POST['nextNonce'];
  if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'myajax-next-nonce' ) )
    die ( 'Busted!');

  $cobertura = get_post_meta($_POST['postId'], 'id_da_galeria', true);;
  echo nggShowGallery($galeria);
  exit;
}
```

this returns as response

```
<h1>Exception thrown</h1><p>No utilities registered for `I_Display_Type_Controller`</p>
```

the ajax works, tried with wp_queries, and a bunch of stuff, all works, all but nextgen gallery related stuff

I think this is the piece of code reporting the error

```
function _retrieve_utility_class($interface, $context='all')
    {
        $class = FALSE;

        if (!$context) $context = 'all';
        if (isset($this->_utilities[$interface])) {
            if (isset($this->_utilities[$interface][$context])) {
                $class = $this->_utilities[$interface][$context];
            }

            // No utility defined for the specified interface
            else {
                if ($context == 'all') $context = 'default';
                $class = $this->_retrieve_utility_class($interface, FALSE);
                if (!$class)
                    throw new Exception("No utility registered for `{$interface}` with the `{$context}` context.");

            }
        }
        else throw new Exception("No utilities registered for `{$interface}`");

        return $class;
    }
```

What more can I try?

EDIT--
I tried to look up on these method calls and changed this file
wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/nextgen_gallery_display/module.nextgen_gallery_display.php
looking for `!is_admin()` changed for true (for test) and the error changed to:

```
<h1>Default Gallery Type Template</h1>
<p>
    This is the default gallery type template, located in:<br/>
    <b>/home/ian/Sites/portalsabores/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/nextgen_gallery_display/templates/index.php</b>.
</p>
<p>
```

I tried to specify the template: `echo nggShowGallery($galeria, 'coberturas', 8);` but nothing changed

it seems that it is related to the fact that wordpress ajax api makes admin calls https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53309/why-might-a-plugins-do-shortcode-not-work-in-an-ajax-request

there is a way to change this?

Answer (score 0):

this answer made it possible to me:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96026/nextgen-gallery-how-to-get-picture-url-by-gallery-id

I changed the ajax return to a template part using [SMK theme view](https://github.com/Smartik89/SMK-Theme-View/blob/master/functions.php), the ajax action became:

```
function noix_galeria_click() {
  // check nonce
  $nonce = $_POST['nextNonce'];
  if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'myajax-next-nonce' ) )
    die ( 'Busted!');

  $cobertura = get_post_meta($_POST['postId'], 'id_da_galeria', true);

  ob_start();
?>
<?php smk_get_template_part('parts/coberturas/galeria-principal.php', array(
              'galeria' => $cobertura,
              'post_id' => $_POST['postId']
              )); ?>
<?php
  $output = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  echo $output;
  die();
}
```

with smk you can send variables through get_template_part function

On `galeria-principal.php` I have

```
<?php
global $nggdb;

$gall_ids = $nggdb->get_ids_from_gallery($this->galeria); // smk allow you to return the variables as properties of $this
$images = $nggdb->find_images_in_list($gall_ids); // see these methods at
// wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/ngglegacy/lib/ngg-db.php
// then build the template
$evento = get_post($this->post_id);
?>
<...>
      <?php foreach ($images as $image): ?>
        <?php
          // I build this path because imageURL was empty, not sure why
          $file_path = get_home_url() .$image->_ngiw->_cache['path'] . '/' . $image->_ngiw->_cache['filename'];
          $file_desc = $image->_ngiw->_cache['description'];
          ?>
        <li>
          <img src="<?php echo $file_path ?>" alt="<?php echo $file_desc ?>">
        </li>
      <?php endforeach ?>

<...>
```

This will work correctly with ajax